# Service fabric increase stateless service instance without re-deployment

Tags: powershell, scale, azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to increase number of instance for stateless service on Service Fabric please? We can update the application manifest to increase the number however that will require a deployment. Is there a way to do that via Service Fabric Explorer or Powershell please?

Thank you very much 
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using the Update-ServiceFabricService cmdlet

```
Update-ServiceFabricService
  [-Stateless]
  [-ServiceName] <Uri>
  [-Correlation <String[]>]
  [-DefaultMoveCost <String>]
  [-Force]
  [-InstanceCount <Int32>]
  [-Metric <String[]>]
  [-PlacementConstraints <String>]
  [-PlacementPolicy <String[]>]
  [-TimeoutSec <Int32>]
  [-Confirm]
  [-WhatIf]
  [<CommonParameters>]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/update-servicefabricservice?view=azureservicefabricps